# populating select2 with data from stored procedure(mssql)

Tags: jquery, sql-server, ajax, laravel-4

im trying to populate select2 with some data from my query. but cant get it to run correctly...ive search almost all links regarding this but all explanation are just so poorly explained especially for beginners like myself. im using laravel 4 for this projects...

**here is my controller code**

```
    public function showlist() {
    $query2 = "EXEC CFAsp_ColRls";

    $resultset2 = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select($query2);

    return $resultset2;
}
```

**this is my jquery**

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#e2").select2({
        ajax: {
          url: "http://localhost:8080/mytestproject2/public/showlist",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: function (term, page) {
            return {
              q: term
            };
          },
          results: function (data, page) {
            return { result: data };
          }
        }
      });
   });
```

Thank you so much i really need this :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its alright my wrong :D ., thanks for taking some time

i solved my problem by modifying my controller to something like this...

```
    public function showlist() {

    $queryParam = Input::get('q');
    $return = array();

    $query2 = "Select * from sop10100 where sopnumbe like '%".$queryParam."%'";
    $resultset2 = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select($query2);

    foreach ($resultset2 as $value) {
        $return[] = array(
            'id' => $value->DEX_ROW_ID,
            'text' => $value->SOPNUMBE
        );
    }

    return $return;
```

}

figured out that the "q" in this code is a parameter

```
      data: function (term, page) {
        return {
          **q: term**
        };
      },
```

topic closed.

Answer (score 0):

you directly passed Result to the web page, use

```
return json_encode($resultset2);
```

and then try to access. you can't directly assign the data, you need to parse the data to show it in select2 plugin in jquery http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: you need to pass data in specific format. added to my answer

Comment: hmm can u please provide more detailed explanation on how to pass data in a specific format?

Comment: "Loading Remote Data" search it in the link provided, you need to learn we can't give complete solution here. don't feel offensive. because it can't be explained here.